# C# Add current coin count to the coin sum

Tags: c#

I have two scripts: Player script and MainMenu script. The player collects coins and this score shows in the game. When I restart the game, the score resets as it should be. But I want to save coins, collected in the game and show the sum in main menu. How can I do this?

---

Player script

```
void Start()
{
    coin = 0;
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Coin")
    {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
        coin += 1;
        coinCount.text = coin.ToString();
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("coins", coin);
        Debug.Log("Coin");
    }
}
```

---

MainMenu script

```
void Start()
{
    coinText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coins").ToString();

}
```

Comment: What have you tried with regards to saving the data?

Comment: Basically you need to have a "total coins" variable, and you update this at game over (before you reset the game coin count). If you want to persist that over application restarts then you will need to save it somewhere (e.g. database, file, etc.). It's too broad for us to be able to answer here though

Comment: or you can just create a static class and save it there

Comment: @Steve I don't understand what you mean by static class? PlayerPrefs is static.. Unless you mean saving the information into the static class, but that still wouldn't be persistent data.. PlayerPrefs saves persistent data to the registry.

Comment: @BrandonMiller based on his description he want the data to be persistent between games. If that's the case static class would be sufficient. If he wants the data to persist even after the game shuts down he can save it into a file or something. I wouldn't use player prefs to save it since I think that thing should be storing settings only

Comment: @Steve I understand now, I must've misinterpreted. I agree, playerprefs is for storing game options only, Unity has even stated that multiple times on the forums, but I guess people continue to use it for convenience. It's insecure, though, and players can easily modify the registry to change things. That's why I prefer to save to XML and encrypt the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, start by moving `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("coins", coin);` to the GameOver() function. PlayerPrefs makes a call to the registry, and you shouldn't be setting that every time the player gets a coin.

Second, if you want to "Add" the coin you have to the coin that was there previously, just access it like so:

`PlayerPrefs.SetInt("coins", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coins") + coin);`